# Trace full-request / response bodies in AWS ApiGateway (not truncated)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS Api Gateway and **I'd like to trace full request and response**. Some of my integrations are lambdas and some other http endpoints.

I enabled stage > Logs > "Log full requests/responses data" and I can see logs on CloudWatch.

This seemed to be perfect until **I discovered bodies were being TRUNCATED**... There is a limitation of 1024 bytes in ApiGateway sending logs to cloudwatch.

Is there any solution to this?

I am considering using a lambda as a proxy (with http-proxy) as my last option...

Answer (score 13):

As you stated, there is no current known solution to this problem and AWS is aware of the problem.

> API Gateway currently limits log events to 1024 bytes. Log events larger than 1024 bytes, such as request and response bodies, will be truncated by API Gateway before submission to CloudWatch Logs.

You can see additional known issues at the AWS documentation page for API Gateway here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html

Comment: This is still a problem in 2021. Don't understand why they are truncating the logs. They can earn more by allowing huge log payloads. Scaling should not be an issue for them. These cloud providers make good money on charging for logs. Does not make business sense. I have to point my endpoints to a mock endpoint to troubleshoot requests.

Comment: This is still a problem in 2024, because it absolutely undebuggable solution and not looks like something production-ready

Answer (score -1):

According to the AWS documentation, full logging should **not** be turned on in AWS API Gateway, in production, because of PII ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html)).

This is *purely* for development troubleshooting purposes. So the log limitation 1024 bytes continue to exists, because of this.

Comment: This is absolutely irrelevant. It's up to the client to decide whether the debug is enabled or not and this is a technical limitation, not a data confidentiality limitation.