# Log API Gateway Events before EC2 Execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

We're working with AWS and wish to log all incoming http requests from our API Gateway to the EC2 box in their entirety (i.e. not truncated at 1024 bytes). As we know the logging for API Gateway is not configurable our next thought was to place a lambda between the api gateway and EC2 which would intercept the requests, log them to S3, and then forward the request to EC2.

My question is two fold:

How does one submit an API Gateway 'event' to an EC2 instance manually? I've gone over the boto3 documentation and there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this out of the box.

Is this a logical way to log requests in their entirety, or are we missing a built in connector between lambda -> ec2 or request logging in general?

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  #pass event to the ec2
  #log event (done)
  #return response
```

Comment: I am curious to know why you decided to write API gateway logs to an EC2. You can configure API Gateway to write the logs to cloud watch (if you enable it)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable CloudWatch logging for API gateway. By enabling you can find the logs for your requests in the cloud watch.

- Create an IAM role that gives permissions for the API gateway to write logs to cloud watch
- set the IAM role to your API
- set the desired log levels INFO/ERROR
- you can also choose to log the full request/responses
- To enable access logs, you also need to create a log group and provide the arn.

The detailed steps can be found in the reference below.

Hope this helps.

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/

Comment: Unfortunately we run into the issue documented at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365298/trace-full-request-response-bodies-in-aws-apigateway-not-truncated . The bodies of requests are truncated regardless of the selection of that option at 1kb. It is not possible for us to step our calls to under 1 kb. Appreciate your taking a look at it!

Comment: apologies, I get it now.